# Covering your beer during conditioning....??

Tags: beer, conditioning

My first batch is conditioning at room temp right now. I used brown bottles, but threw in a few greens and two cleat just for experimentation..... I have them in a fairly dark room but also covered them with a blanket to fully cut off all light! Good idea? Bad idea? Wast of time?

Answer (score 3):

If you have green and clear glass, then you should cover them, yes.  Otherwise, if they're brown glass in a fairly dark room, I wouldn't worry about it.

If you really want to do an experiment with brown vs. green and clear bottles, then you probably *do* want to expose them to some light, since presumably that would be the point of the experiment.

Not quite sure what sort of answer you're after, here. :/

Comment: I personally use an old shower-curtain, but that's just to simplify cleanup in case there's airlock blowout, or bottle bombs.

Answer (score 0):

I have never covered my beers and haven't had an issue with skunky beer. I do have a dark basement and have mostly covered shelves where I store all of my bottles.

As long as you keep your bottles out of direct sunlight they should be good, so if you want/need to use a blanket to help facilitate that, it's up to you. But it really is dependent on your situation.